# adblocking proxy

Tags: proxy, adblock

I'm a user of several modern browsers and I don't like spam. So I install adblockers, like [ublock origin](https://addons.mozilla.org/ca/firefox/addon/ublock-origin/?src=search). But you have to install extensions in every browser you have and the plugins are not for term browsers (like [links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Links_%28web_browser%29)). So the question is if is there any software outhere acting as central adblocker

I thought in adblocking proxy. Ideally, it could be use EasyList or so for blocking ads, but it could be use DNS blocking directly and spamassassin or some AI for determining heuristically what is and what is not advertising.

Ideally, I would like to configure to remove all ads and add some text according to user preferences: weather information, MOTD (message of the day), etc.

If there is no such software is it difficult to program in any programming language?

Comment: If you want to block ads and the like network-wide, you can implement DNS-based ad blocking such as that provided by Pi-Hole (https://pi-hole.net/), but that won't help with email.

Comment: a couple that i'm aware of are privoxy and proxomitron .... i think that privoxy runs on linux ... not sure about proxomitron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have different approaches.
On is based on DNS blocking, and pi-hole, as @DopeGhoti said, is the best choice: you feed it with ad blocklists (you can find it on blocklist.site, fo example) and eventually with regular expressions.
The other one is filtering traffic with an http / https proxy, such as squid cache: you can feed its block list with the very same lists of pi-hole.

The best way depends on how many clients you do have to serve / protect / filter and what protcols (i.e. udp doesn't go through http(s) proxies).

If you intend to block emails, you can configure an MTA/LDA (postfix + dovecot for example) with rspamd.

This is just an overview of tecniques you can use; if you ever need specific infos    I'd be glad to provide them, accordingly to your environment's needings.

Comment: Is there a tool for replace adds with some useful messages like Message of the day? Another question: do all this software download the page and then apply filters or they avoid to download un-useful parts?

Comment: If you perform a DNS blocking, the page is not loaded at all; in both case you can put a deny_info page that is displayed when you try to reach a forbidden page, anyhow I'm not that sure you can just "replace" banners with a motd. Then keep in mind that, unless you opt for an SSL inspection and bumping, you cannot replace https pages due to certicates.